# Importing javascript files on WaveMaker

Tags: javascript, external, wavemaker

We have been using WaveMaker and wanted to know how we can go about importing an external javascript file using the platform ?

Comment: What version of WaveMaker are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1. The external JS file should be imported into a folder in resources
2. The file path has to be given in login.html of the Web-App
3. The file path should be of the form "/projectname/foldername/filename.js/"
4. The functions in the external JS file can be accessed in the login page through its script and the function invoked here is from a sample js file.

Answer (score 0):

The following works if using WaveMaker 6.  This probably doesn't work with newer versions of WaveMaker.

Instead of having to add it to each project, try editing `index.html` in the `webapproot` directory and add you external js file:

```
<!-- Boot Wavemaker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<path to javascript file>/sha512.js"></script>
```

Then, in order to have this work correctly in your development environment, add a context tag to `server.xml` just above the projects directory:

```
        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
            <Context docBase="c:/<Path To Javascript Filet" path="<path to javascript file matching whats in index.html>" reloadable="true"/>
        </Host>
```

In the above `Context` tag, `docBase` is the local folder with js and `path` should match the path placed in `index.html`.

Doing this you can use the javascript file across all projects without having to add it to `resources` in the project.